# React native disable auto rotate

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, screen-orientation

I need to disable auto rotation feature in react-native application.

The application should support portrait and landscape orientation but the user should can`t rotation screen. Now I have used react-native-orientation but this module only checked orientation and change it to necessary value.

So I need rotate screen only programmatically.

RN Version: 0.33

Comment: No. Im should support portrait and landscape so I can`t disable this orientation on Xcode.

Comment: I can't seem to understand what your problem is. Please post what you have done till now

Answer (score 2):

You can set your Xcode Device Orientation
[image]

Set in your android manifest file:
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Or You can set it using `Dimensions`. Something like this:

```
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', ({ window: { width, height } }) => {
    const orientation = width > height ? 'LANDSCAPE' : 'PORTRAIT';
}
```

Or you can use `react-native-orientation` to lock the screen on portrait or landscape just as you need. I have a working example in my github: https://github.com/soutot/react-native-orientation-test

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Orientation.lockToLandscape();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Text>This is my content</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Hope it helps